# Live data transfer over USB

Tags: android, usb, data-transfer

I'm trying to figure out how to transfer frames rendered on a computer to an android phone. Wifi and Bluetooth aren't fast enough for a smooth framerate, but the data transfer speed across the USB connector is more than enough (up to 480 megabytes/ second). Thing is, I can't figure out how to do it- there's nothing in the Android docs and I haven't found anything online. How can I access the USB connection?

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the USB connection in any documented and supported fashion.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at all? Are there any hacks that allow it?
It's not an app for publication, and I don't mind messing with my own phone.

Comment: Turns out you can do it with socket programming and $adb forward <local> <remote> in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning debug mode on and using adb to connect to the device. You can manually push files to the phone (e.g. to the sdcard) which you can in turn periodically check in your app. You can also write files the other way around (from your app) and have your PC app check that file, again over ADB. That way you can establish simple protocols for communication.

I also need this right now, but a bit more difficult since I try to access the phone from an programmable integrated device with USB host chip inside. Which probably means reverse engineering ADB...

Either way, it's a pretty hacky solution but it should work over all phones as long as debug mode is turned on, which makes it feasible.